# Using fiddler with a C# application + ip:port proxy

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy, fiddler

I am working on a project that involves using ip:port proxies. My C# application uses geckofx web browser, which allows me to specify a proxy to route traffic through. I need to be able to see the traffic in fiddler, but whenever I try and load a webpage via my C# application's web browser(configured with a ip:port proxy, I do not see any traffic in fiddler. I also do not see any traffic without a proxy.

Browsing through a web browser like chrome, I can see all the traffic that goes through...what am I missing?? Why can I not view traffic from my C# app?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is a proxy server; it sees traffic that is sent to it. It registers itself as the default system proxy on startup and reverts that on shutdown. If your application manually specifies another proxy, it won't send its traffic to Fiddler.

To fix that, either configure the client to point at Fiddler and configure Fiddler to "chain" to your upstream proxy, or configure your other proxy to "chain" to Fiddler.

It's probably simplest to do the former: set the upstream proxy inside Tools > Fiddler Options, or make it IE's default proxy when Fiddler isn't running.

Comment: What if I need to run multiple instances of my C# application, each using different ip:port proxies?

Comment: The same guidance applies; you could chain those proxies to Fiddler. Or, you could add a custom header (e.g. X-Proxy-To: ip:port) and have Fiddler detect that header and set the X-OverrideGateway flag on the Session, then remove the header.

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I just do not understand what you mean by "chain those proxies to Fiddler". And for the custom header, you mean add a custom header from my C# app and then have fiddler route the traffic to the proxy? In that case, would I just set the geckofx proxy to use localhost?

Comment: If you control the "ip:port" proxies, you could configure them to send their traffic through a Fiddler instance. If you don't control them, this obviously won't work. For the custom header route, yes, you add a custom header from the C# application and have its proxy setting pointed to 127.0.0.8888, and then you have code in Fiddler look at that header when deciding where to send traffic next. Now, if you can't add a custom header, then you have your app send a HTTP message to Fiddler that says, in effect "For all subsequent requests from this process (see X-ProcessInfo) send traffic to ..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `localhost` in your URL, then you need to add a dot (`.`) to the end of `localhost`, like this:

```
http://localhost.:56789/YourPage.aspx
```

Note: `56789` is a made up port number, but you will need to use the one that gets generated for you automatically when running via Visual Studio.

Comment: That's true (.NET bypasses proxies for localhost addresses) but will not be sufficient if he's manually specifying a proxy for his application.

Comment: Good point EricLaw, but I did caveat my answer with "if..." LOL